# Why does the Spearman rank coefficient multiply distance by 6?

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

I have been trying to learn more about the inner workings of different correlations lately and noticed that the Pearson correlation so far has been easy to figure out the why's and how's of. However, I have found the Spearman correlation is quite straightforward to calculate, but I'm having trouble understanding why there is even a 6 here in the first place:

[image: spearman]

Is there a simple explanation as to why? I haven't seen any questions here that address this.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient.  Simply put, "6" is a natural consequence of expanding sample pearson correlation when the data is $(R(X_i), R(Y_i)), i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Comment: That doesn't really say much about the mechanics of what it is doing though. Perhaps you can elaborate.

Comment: Have you carefully gone through (click to expand) the "Proof" box under its [Definition and calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Definition_and_calculation) section?